# Play video in image/video gallery in JS or jQuery on large image click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found many helpful sites for image gallery with JS/jQuery but not much with video in gallery.

I need help with **playing video as part of the image gallery**, once you click on a large image (NOT click on thumbnail) play video.

For example, this site already has full code for image gallery.
I just need to add the video at the end of the gallery to play video.
http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_demo_image_swap_gallery.htm

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-image-swap-gallery/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Image swap on hover
    $("#gallery li img").hover(function(){
        $('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
    });
    // Image preload
    var imgSwap = [];
     $("#gallery li img").each(function(){
        imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
        imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
    });
    $(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
```

```css
#gallery li {
display: inline;
margin-right: 3px;
}
#gallery #main-img {
background: url(images/bg_img.png) no-repeat 0 0;
padding: 26px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="gallery">
    <img src="images/gallery/img_1.jpg" alt="" id="main-img" />
    <ul>
      <li><img src="images/gallery/thumb/img_1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/gallery/thumb/img_3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/gallery/thumb/img_4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/gallery/thumb/img_5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/gallery/thumb/img_6.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/gallery/thumb/img_7.jpg" alt="" data-video="www.video.com?videoparameters_autoplay="1" "/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Would I add **data attribute** to last image I want the video to be?
$('.gallery,image7 only').click(function() {
       var playVideo = '';
       $('.video').hide();
     });

call function to click on image 7 to play video,
if image 6 then hide, etc. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> call function to click on image 7 to play video, if image 6 then hide, etc. Hope this makes sense.

Sorry, it doesn't make sense. If I understand what you are trying to do is make the `#main-img` a video when the last image is clicked on. Earlier I think you said:

> I need help with playing video as part of the image gallery, once you click on a large image (NOT click on thumbnail) play video.

Isn't image 7 a thumb? Well if this demo doesn't behave exactly the way you wanted, I'm sure this'll help you in the right direction.

The list of changes are:

- Added a video element `#vid` next to the `#main-img` with the class`.hide`
- The last image `#vidImg` has a delegated click event that when triggered will `toggleClass` `.hide` on `#vid` and `#main-img` so now if one exists, the other one doesn't.

### SNIPPET

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Image swap on hover
  $("#gallery li img").hover(function() {
    $('#main-img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
  });
  // Image preload
  var imgSwap = [];
  $("#gallery li img").each(function() {
    imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
    imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
  });
  $(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
  this.each(function() {
    $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
  });
}


$("#vidImg").on('click', function() {
    $('#vid').toggleClass('hide');
    $('#main-img').toggleClass('hide');
  });
```

```css
#gallery li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
}
#gallery #main-img {
  background: url(images/bg_img.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  padding: 26px;
}
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="gallery">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150/000/fff?text=0" alt="" id="main-img" />
  <video id="vid" class="hide" poster="http://placehold.it/200x150/fff/000?text=VIDEO" src="http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vid1.mp4" width="200" height="150" controls></video>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x75/000/fff?text=1" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x75/fff/000?text=2" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x75/000/fff?text=3" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x75/fff/000?text=4" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x75/000/fff?text=5" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img id="vidImg" src="http://placehold.it/100x75/000/fff?text=VIDEO" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for suggesting a new code.
Sorry, you are correct, what I meant was click on the large image, "gallery/img_7.jpg" (not image 7 thumbnail, "thumb/img_7.jpg"). [
*this person used same img name for both thumb & large so the code just takes out the thumb folder)

Your suggested code clicks on the thumb, I need help with clicking on the large image instead to play video! Thanks!!!!